# How to make a permanent code changes in coded UI Test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When I record my test using Coded UI Test I typed `10` in a textbox in one of my application windows.
It recorded like this and shows this in `XYZUIMap.Designer.cs`

Generated Code

```
// Type '        10.  ' in 'uxTextBox' text box
uIUxTextBoxEdit2.Text = this.GetAndFillupARInvoiceLinesFormParams.UIUxTextBoxEdit2Text;
```

But when I playback my test it fails at this textbox

If I modify my code in the designer file (`XYZUIMap.Designer.cs`) like this, it works perfectly alright

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(uIUxTextBoxEdit2,
    this.GetAndFillupARInvoiceLinesFormParams.UIUxTextBoxEdit2Text,
    ModifierKeys.None);
```

I know that it is a temporary fix as I am not supposed to do any code changes to Designer.cs file

How do I make my changes permanent? and where to change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it bad to edit the UIMap.designer.cs file in a Visual Studio Coded UI test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670364/why-is-it-bad-to-edit-the-uimap-designer-cs-file-in-a-visual-studio-coded-ui-tes)

Answer (score -1):

Make your changes in the .cs file that is generated with the Designer File.

So XYZUIMap.cs

Create a method to preform the actions you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398062.aspx#UIMapCS