# Error observed after copying code from UIMap.Designer.cs to UIMap.cs

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, htmlcontrols

I am getting following error after copying the auto-generated code from UIMap.Designer.cs to UIMap.cs

Ambiguity between 'Test_7.UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument.UIDJComboBox' and 'Test_7.UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument.UIDJComboBox'

I am getting this error on following line of code in my codedUITestMethod -

> Mouse.Click(this.UIMap.UIReviewyourshoppingcaWindow.UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument.UIDJComboBox);

I want to create custom code for my coded UI test, but I am unable to do so due to this error.

Following is the code which i have moved in UIMap.cs file -

```
    public class UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument : HtmlDocument
    {
        #region Properties
        public HtmlComboBox UIDJComboBox
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIDJComboBox1 == null))
                {
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1 = new HtmlComboBox(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.SearchProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Name] = "DJ";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.LabeledBy] = null;
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Size] = "0";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Title] = "D J";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.ItemCount] = "52";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.Class] = "form-control control-width form-select DJ-required";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "name=\"DJ\" title=\"Dms";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.FilterProperties[HtmlComboBox.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "2";
                    this.mUIDJComboBox1.WindowTitles.Add("Review your shopping cart");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIDJComboBox1;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private HtmlComboBox mUIDJComboBox1;
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670364/why-is-it-bad-to-edit-the-uimap-designer-cs-file-in-a-visual-studio-coded-ui-tes/19678182#19678182 and read item (3) more than once.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the answer in the post. It mentioned the process to move the action into UIMap.cs. I want to move only the captured control into UIMap.cs which is giving me the mentioned error. Any way I can bypass this error ?

Comment: After moving the code what is `this` and what is its type? Showing one line of code is not enough. What code did you move, from where and into where - not the files, we know that, but which methods/classes/properties?

Comment: I have updated my details. Thanks.

Comment: I have moved this code in UIMap partial class in UIMap.cs

Comment: The UI Map is made up of many classes. I think you have moved a **property** of one class into a totally different class. Hence the value of `this` has changed from the original class into the new class, hence the error message.

Comment: Yes Adrian, I moved this code which was part of public class UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument : HtmlDocument into public partial class UIMap
Hence the error.
OK now I have put the code in UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument : HtmlDocument and renamed mUIDJComboBox to mUIDJComboBox1. But I am getting error Ambiguity between 'Test_7.UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument.UIDJComboBox' and 'Test_7.UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument.UIDJComboBox'
What can be done to resolve this ?

Comment: The latest edit to the question has changed almost everything, it is effectively a new question. I think the new error message means there are two declarations for `public class UIReviewyourshoppingcaDocument...`. Perhaps you have not **moved** the class but you have **copied** it. Hence one in `uimap.cs` and another in `uimap.designer.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving Methods to **UIMap.cs** using **UI.uitest** file. if you do it manually whenever your **UIMap.uitest** file will be saved it will generate code again. for that reason you are getting an error for Ambiguity.

This is the one way task as you can move methods from **UIMap.cs** to **UIMap.designer.cs**

refer to this post for more details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I think that the problem is that he is trying to move a "ui control" so it can be modified as evidenced by https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fdfc967-71ac-4a42-845a-cc63a3f11c48/the-button-move-code-to-uimapcs-is-disabled