# Coded UI - How to Capture Image After a Mouse Click Event

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

What is the best option of capturing image after each mouse click in recorded session of Coded UI?

For example, in UIMap.Designer.Cs file I have entered image capturing lines:

```
Mouse.Click(uIOutagesandSafetyHyperlink, new Point(62, 2));
Image MSOPic1 = UITestControl.Desktop.CaptureImage();
MSOPic1.Save(@"C:\Automation\TestAutomation\web\Recordings\FullSite1\Screenshots\MSO\HomePage_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".png");
```

The above code takes a screenshot but it does not take the current browser's screenshot, just captures another screen where the current browser window does not exist. How can I capture screenshot of the active browser where the test is taking place?

One more question: Does Visual Studio provide an alternative way to capture images during playback? Like through configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One more question: Does Visual Studio provide an alternative way to capture images during playback? Like through configuration?

By default coded ui test should take a screenshot with each action it does. 
You can find these screenshots in the html outputs for your tests.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159363.aspx

If in any case it is not enabled for your tests you have to set:
`Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;`

If you want to have this setting in all tests and for all actions call it in the [TestInitialize()] method of each test you want to apply it to.

Like so:

```
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks hyperionb. Placing the code you mentioned in TestInitialize method worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `UITestControl` class has a `CaptureImage` method. To get an image of the current browser, find its `UITestControl` object (which may be derived from that) and call its `CaptureImage` method.

Please do not edit the `uimap.designer.cs` file as it is an auto-generated file and your edits may be lost. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670364/why-is-it-bad-to-edit-the-uimap-designer-cs-file-in-a-visual-studio-coded-ui-tes/19678182#19678182).

Comment: Thanks Adrian for pointing this out. I will look more into the link you've mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have updated my code and using UIMap.cs instead of UIMap.Designer.cs file as you had recommended. Thank you for this.